# How to moderate elements of a list while in a loop

Tags: python, list, loops

How do I make sure that the elements in b don't go below 0 or above 10?

I.e. when 5 decreases to 0 in list b, how can I get the program to increase it back to 1 and then make increments of 1?

```
a = [2, 5, 7]
b = []
m = True
counter = 1

while m == True:

    for i in a:

        if i >= 5:
            i -= counter
            b.append(i)
        else:
            i += counter
            b.append(i)

        if len(a) == len(b):
            counter += 1
            print(b)
            b.clear()

        if counter == 15:
            m = False

"""
Current output: 
[2, 5, 7]
[3, 4, 6]
[4, 3, 5]
[5, 2, 4]
[6, 1, 3]
[7, 0, 2]
[8, -1, 1]
[9, -2, 0]
[10, -3, -1]
[11, -4, -2]

Expected output:
[2, 5, 7]
[3, 4, 6]
[4, 3, 5]
[5, 2, 4]
[6, 1, 3]
[7, 0, 2]
[8, 1, 1]
[9, 2, 0]
[10, 3, 1]
[9, 4, 2]
"""
```

Comment: Try using modulus operator %

Comment: Very much as you have said: write an `if` statement to check `i`; if it hits 0, reset `counter` to 1 and increment immediately.  Where are you stuck with writing that code?  What have you tried?

Comment: @Prune Hi, thanks for the response. I think tinkering with the counter will also impact the increments of the other elements. I tried replacing list a if any element + counter == 10 or 0 with list b, then resetting counter to 0. This was so that the conditions i put in place originally will have to be met again but with the elements from list b in list a. Sorry if this is a bit confusing!

Comment: Yes, it's confusing -- because you haven't told us what the program is supposed to do.  Look at the posting guidelines, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Among other things, we expect the current and expected output.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do @mke? What is the structure in your output list, and how does it relate to your input list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I am completely following what you are after, but below is an approach to getting your expected output (I wasn't following what you were trying to do with your while loop, so I just looped this 15 times based on your max counter value - but you could do something else with that outer loop).

```
numbers = [2, 5, 7]
switches = [True, False, False]
output = list()

for _ in range(15):
    for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
        # keep numbers between 0 and 10
        if number == 0:
            switches[i] = True
        elif number == 10:
            switches[i] = False

        # increment or decrement number based on corresponding "switch"    
        if switches[i]:
            number += 1
            output.append(number)
        else:
            number -= 1
            output.append(number)

        # print and reset
        if len(output) == len(numbers):
            numbers = output
            output = list()
            print(numbers)

# OUTPUT
# [3, 4, 6]
# [4, 3, 5]
# [5, 2, 4]
# [6, 1, 3]
# [7, 0, 2]
# [8, 1, 1]
# [9, 2, 0]
# [10, 3, 1]
# [9, 4, 2]
# [8, 5, 3]
# [7, 6, 4]
# [6, 7, 5]
# [5, 8, 6]
# [4, 9, 7]
# [3, 10, 8]
```